# How to combine imported and local resources in WPF user control

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I'm writing several WPF user controls that need both shared and individual resources.

I have figured out the syntax for loading resources from a separate resource file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewResources.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

However, when I do this, I cannot also add resources locally, like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewResources.xaml" />
    <!-- Doesn't work: -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        ...
    </ControlTemplate>
    <style x:key="textBoxWithError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        ...
    </style>
    ...
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I've had a look at ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries, but that only lets me merge more than one external dictionary, not define further resources locally.

I must be missing something trivial?

It should be mentioned: I'm hosting my user controls in a WinForms project, so putting shared resources in App.xaml is not really an option.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

I figured it out. The solution involves MergedDictionaries, but the specifics must be just right, like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- This works: -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            ...
        </ControlTemplate>
        <style x:key="textBoxWithError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            ...
        </style>
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

That is, the local resources must be nested **within** the ResourceDictionary tag. So the example [here](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/05/27/How-do-I-separate-out-resources-into-multiple-files-in-WPF.aspx) is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

You can define local resources inside MergedDictionaries section:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- import resources from external files -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewResources.xaml" />

            <ResourceDictionary>
                <!-- put local resources here -->
                <Style x:key="textBoxWithError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    ...
                </Style>
                ...
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [MergedDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries.aspx).

I got the following example from  [here.](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=09ca2c76-4b45-4919-8747-eae036a7095e)

File1

```
<ResourceDictionary 
  xmlns=" http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation "
  xmlns:x=" http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml " > 
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="TextStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Lucida Sans" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#58290A" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

File 2

```
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="TextStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. His example seems right, but doesn't actually work. I get the message "The property 'Resources' is set more than once".

Comment: I know about MergedDictionaries. But they don't let me combine an external dictionary reference with locally defined resources the way I want. As already stated, there's an example on the page you refer to, but it doesn't work.

Comment: For anyone getting that "set more than once" error: Every other resources need to be within the first <ResourceDictionary> tag.