# Hamburger menu MahApps C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, hamburger-menu

I trying to open hamburger menu sample in my project (App1)

When i add

```
xmlns:core="clr-namespace:App1;assembly=App1"
```

this below isnt working

```
<core:SelectedItemToContentConverter Key="SelectedItemToContentConverter" />
```

It tells

> All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.
>
> Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.
>
> The tag 'SelectedItemToContentConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:App1;assembly=App1'. Line 27 Position 14.

I have `D:\VS\P4\App1\App1\SelectedItemToContentConverter2.cs` in main project folder with correct namespace.

Do you have any advice? thank you

Comment: Please post the code for `SelectedItemContentConverter2`, or run a "Build" and see if it gives you a specific error.

Comment: try follow that answer : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931864/wpf-compile-error-idictionary-must-have-a-key-attribute)