# Adding Converter declaration

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

I try to insert an `Image` to my `GUI` application by means of a `Binding` and a `Converter`. I create an instance of a value converter in the resources of my `MainWindow`:

```
"xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:MyApp"    

<Window.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Resc">
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="StylesDictionary.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>

     <my1:DirectionToImageConverter x:Key="DirectionToImageConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

However, when I try to run the application I get the following exception:

> **''Resources' property has already been set on 'MainWindow'.' Line number '16' and
>
>         line position '11'.**

Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You need to put your converter in the resource dictonary, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333786/how-to-combine-imported-and-local-resources-in-wpf-user-control).

```
<Window.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Resc">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StylesDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <my1:DirectionToImageConverter x:Key="DirectionToImageConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Please, see the question below